# how to setup initial cente in opencv python using cv2.KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS

Tags: python, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

how to set bestLabel vector in python, what will size of bestLabel,is this have two position from samples.

```
compactness,label,center=cv2.kmeans(samples,K,bestLabel,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS)
```

I am struggling to give my initial means to kmeans.
My samples is 70x2 array including 70 samples with 2 features.
K=2.
plz give me python example of bestLabel generate.

Answer (score 2):

You must provide both the initial centroids you want and the initial labels for every sample.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


def main():

    seed = 1
    nclusters = 2

    np.random.seed(seed) # Get always same random numpys
    data = np.random.random(size=(100, 100)).astype(np.float32)
    centers = np.array([[75], [125]])
    labels = np.random.randint(nclusters,
                               size=(data.shape[0], data.shape[1]),
                               dtype=np.int32)


    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 100, 1.0)

    reshaped_data = np.reshape(data, data.shape[0] * data.shape[1])
    reshaped_labels = np.reshape(labels, (labels.shape[0] * labels.shape[1], 1))

    _, new_labels, center = cv2.kmeans(data=reshaped_data,
                                       K=nclusters,
                                       bestLabels=reshaped_labels,
                                       criteria=criteria,
                                       attempts=10,
                                       flags=cv2.KMEANS_USE_INITIAL_LABELS,
                                       centers=centers)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

I read the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html). I did't find the option to initialize centorids with vector. There are two possible ways how to set initial centroids:

- cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS: fast but labels will be diffrent with each clustering
- cv2.KMEANS_PP_CENTERS: gives same results for the same input but is slow

Here is an example of running, kmeans in python using opencv.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X = np.random.randint(25,50,(25,2))
Y = np.random.randint(60,85,(25,2))
Z = np.vstack((X,Y))

# convert to np.float32
Z = np.float32(Z)

# define criteria and apply kmeans()
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
ret,label,center=cv2.kmeans(Z,2,None,criteria,10,cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)

# Now separate the data, Note the flatten()
A = Z[label.ravel()==0]
B = Z[label.ravel()==1]

# Plot the data
plt.scatter(A[:,0],A[:,1])
plt.scatter(B[:,0],B[:,1],c = 'r')
plt.scatter(center[:,0],center[:,1],s = 80,c = 'y', marker = 's')
plt.xlabel('Height'),plt.ylabel('Weight')
plt.show()
```

If you have to set your initial centorids you can use sklearn library. Documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html).